# Calling function<T>

Tags: c#, function, syntax

Hello I don't know how to call the next function can you please help me here.

the function Checks whether the value is defined Enum value. Throws exception if it is not.
 Warning: fails for [Flag] type of enums

```
public static T FailIfEnumIsNotDefined<T>(this T enumValue, string message = null)
        where T:struct
    {
        var enumType = typeof (T);

        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("Type {0} is not an Enum, therefore it cannot be checked if it is Defined not have defined.", enumType.FullName));
        } 
        else if (!Enum.IsDefined(enumType, enumValue))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("{1} Value {0} is not does not have defined value in Enum of type {0}. It should not be...", enumType.FullName, message ?? ""));
        }

        return enumValue;
    }
```

I have tried something like this but I get errors.

```
        var valueFormatted = tobeTested.FailIfNullOrEmptyEnumerable<string>();
```

Comment: You would have to give us more information on what the function should do

Comment: `string` is a `class` not a `struct` and the way you call the method is incorrect.

Comment: Making extension for the provided enum type doesnt seem to be of use. Either you need extension for a string or object. Check my answer if thats wat u need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function represents an [`extension method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for Enum types. You cannot invoke it on `string` as you are currently attempting to do because it will blow at runtime. Look how inside the function it checks whether the generic `T` parameter is an enum. Unfortunately there's no generic constraint for enum types.

So assuming you have the following enum type:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Foo, Bar, Baz
}
```

and an instance of this enum:

```
MyEnum e = MyEnum.Bar;
```

you could call the extension method:

```
e.FailIfEnumIsNotDefined();
```

or:

```
e.FailIfEnumIsNotDefined("some message");
```

Also don't forget to bring the extension method in scope by adding the proper using directive to the namespace in which this method is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have defined any `enum`:

```
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        One,
        Two
    }
```

Then, you can call your extension method using:

```
MyEnum enumValue = MyEnum.One;
enumValue.FailIfEnumIsNotDefined<MyEnum>();
```

or

```
enumValue.FailIfEnumIsNotDefined<MyEnum>("error message");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse any string or object you should create the extension for string or object as shown below:

```
 public static T FailIfEnumIsNotDefined<T>(this object enumValue, string message = null) where T : struct
        {
            var enumType = typeof(T);

            if (!enumType.IsEnum)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("...");
            }
            else if (!Enum.IsDefined(enumType, enumValue))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("...");
            }

            return (T)Enum.Parse(enumType, enumValue.ToString());// (T)enumValue;
        }
```

use is as follows

```
 var a = "One".FailIfEnumIsNotDefined<MyEnum>();

public enum MyEnum
    {
        One,
        Two
    }
```

This should solve the problem.

If you are creating the extension for string u need not do ToString() in parse.